# How to populate treeview in backgroundworker C#

Tags: c#, treeview, backgroundworker, populate

I have those below code that populate a treeview named treeView1 with data from JSON file using JSONnet. If I open a large json file, the UI hang during the populating progress, so how can I make everything happen in a backgroundworker and show a progressbar for populating progress? thanks

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string jsonfile = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);                
            try
            {
                var jsondata = JObject.Parse(jsonfile);
                treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
                AddObjectNodes(jsondata, "DATA", treeView1.Nodes);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid JSON");                    
            }
        }
    }
    private void AddObjectNodes(JObject @object, string name, TreeNodeCollection parent)
    {
        var node = new TreeNode(name);
        parent.Add(node);

        foreach (var property in @object.Properties())
        {
            AddTokenNodes(property.Value, property.Name, node.Nodes);
        }
    }

    private void AddArrayNodes(JArray array, string name, TreeNodeCollection parent)
    {
        var node = new TreeNode(name);
        parent.Add(node);

        for (var i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            AddTokenNodes(array[i], string.Format("[{0}]", i), node.Nodes);
        }
    }

    private void AddTokenNodes(JToken token, string name, TreeNodeCollection parent)
    {
        if (token is JValue)
        {
            parent.Add(new TreeNode(string.Format("{0}: {1}", name, ((JValue)token).Value)));
        }
        else if (token is JArray)
        {
            AddArrayNodes((JArray)token, name, parent);
        }
        else if (token is JObject)
        {
            AddObjectNodes((JObject)token, name, parent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you google for that before asking here? Pretty sure this is a very commonly asked question...

Comment: So you mentioned BackgroundWorker....do some research on it and how to use it......Other options are to System.Threading.Thread or System.Threading.Task. Also keep in mind that you will need to invoke controls such as your TreeView if you are updating it from within BackgrouWorker/Thread/Task

Comment: Also apply BeginUpdate and EndUpdate methods before and after each loops in which you add nodes to the tree to make it faster.

Comment: @SuperOli, how do you expect google to have information for searches if no one makes posts like these?